# Accessing static resources from another module on Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on a Spring MVC multimodule project. I'ven trying to make it modularized to split the differents funtionalities.

The problem I've found is that I wanted to create a module just with the static resources of the project (to isolate the front work from the back) accessing it from the web module. Is that possible?

I've been trying to modify the next Spring code to reach it without succeed:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="classpath*:/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="file://..." />
```

I've added the maven dependencies from the differents modules correctly (I can use methods from other projects without any problem)

Edit: That's the project schema:

- project-parent: contains the modules dependencies (web,business,resources)
- project-business: contains the business code (helpers, model, repositories...)
- project-web: contains the web code (controllers, services..and the views where I call the resources, including the Spring code to call the statics resources and the maven dependencies from the other modules (business and resources))
- project-resources: contains the static resources

Comment: Are your resources under your project?

Comment: To try to clarify it I edit the main post to put my project schema

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you solve?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven, look into the [Maven WAR plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html), it's about the only way to do it from Maven. From ant you can write a target that does the exact same thing; which copies the resources from one location to the other at build time.